# 403 error for QuickSight Dashboard thumbnails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-quicksight

0
I have multiple QuickSight Dashboards and none of the Dashboard thumbnails are visible. The browser console displays a 404 Forbidden error. The URL is a presigned link to an S3 bucket e.g.

https://sn-thumbnail-images-prod-eu-west-2.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/123456789123/dashboard/thumbnail/c064825c-7e14-456c-9d18-0f6eb906d6eb.png?X-Amz-Security-Token=.....

I do not control this S3 bucket, as far as I can tell it is a central bucket created by AWS where they store QuickSight preview images.

Why are the dashboard thumbnails not visible?

My account has full administrator access

Comment: Thumbnails are created when an Analysis is modified/saved. Creating a Dashboard from a Template does not result in thumbnails being generated. 

Is your Dashboard created from an Analysis you created - or from a template?

Comment: thanks @mkst This was the solution and I know this was a while back but I spoke to the AWS QuickSight Solution Architect about this and even they didn't know this lol

Answer (score 0):

- Do you see this error when looking at network traffic within your browser developer tools while using QuickSight console or are you doing something special?
- Do all users have the problem? If you face the problem seeing the thumbnails while connecting using VPC, can you try without using VPC?